# How to test method with callable argument in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, phpunit

There are some private static methods in a class. Something like

```
class Some {
    …
    private static function getSome($x) {…}
    …
}
```

It is used as callable from within other public method the same 'Some' Class

```
$a = self::getSuperSome(
    [__CLASS__, 'getSome']
);
```

When I tried to change to

```
$actual = Some::getSuperSome(
    ['Some', 'getSome'] // Should be changed ?
);
```

Got error from PHPUnit

*TypeError: Argument blah-blah passed to App\Some::getSuperSome() must be callable, array given…' blah-blah*

How can I change name of args in SomeTest class of PHPUnit to test getSuperSame?

Comment: Unit tests are for testing the public interface and NOT the private/protected methods. Also, you should not use static methods to begin with. We have option to namespace functions in PHP now.

Comment: @tereško I would like to test **public** getSuperSome method. If I change visibility of getSome to **public** I have got the same error message.

Comment: `[__CLASS__, 'getSome']` is quite valid as a callable (if done in correct scope), there must be some other issue somewhere. Please consider providing more code (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: and please **do** consider tereško's comment